# Error 506: Class not defined: 'FileSystemObject'

Tags: vba, io, subroutine

I'm writing a VBA script for a program called "ScorBase". I'm trying to call a subroutine that creates a text file yet I"m encountering this error "506".

this is the code that I'm writhing:

```
    Sub emailFile()

' Declare a TextStream.
Dim stream 
'As TextStream

dim fso
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' Create a TextStream.
Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\eladt\Desktop\creatFile\Mail.txt", True)

stream.WriteLine "user Email."
stream.WriteLine "Maki"
stream.WriteLine "Nigeri"
stream.WriteLine "Sashimi"
stream.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you: `set fso = new Scripting.FileSystemObject` or `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` ?

Comment: still throws the same error

Comment: I hate to state the obvious, but do you have "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" added as a "Reference"? Tools > References > Check "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" > OK

Comment: Does `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` work elsewhere on the same machine (E.g. from Excel/Word or a .vbs file) ? FYI you do not need the FSO to write a text file with VBA.

Comment: Are you working on a Mac ?

Comment: I'm not on a mac, but i am running the script through a different program (not from excel), i have the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" checked.

Comment: Alex k, when i add CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") and run it straight from excel vb it works. it also worked before the changes. the problem is when i load the script to a program called "Scorbase"  and for some reason  i cant use "Dim" and "As".

Comment: Alex, what other way is there to write a file in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An much simpler approach without using any external references:

```
Sub MM_Email_To_File()

Dim FF As Integer
FF = FreeFile

'// The file will be created if it doesn't exist
Open "C:\Users\eladt\Desktop\creatFile\Mail.txt" For Output As #FF

    Print #FF, "User Email"
    Print #FF, "Maki"
    Print #FF, "Nigeri"
    Print #FF, "Sashimi"

Close #FF

End Sub
```

You can check out [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163.aspx) for more information on I/O operation in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

If late binding from another application works then there is an issue with the VBA environment your 3rd party application is hosting, possibly it is performing some type of sandboxing.

You don't need any external libraries to write to a file, you can try to do it natively:

```
Dim hf As Integer
hf = FreeFile

Open "C:\Users\eladt\Desktop\creatFile\Mail.txt" For Output As #hf

Print #hf, "user Email."
Print #hf, "Maki"
Print #hf, "Nigeri"
Print #hf, "Sashimi"

Close #hf
```

Comment: Thanks Alex K. it did the job:)

Answer (score 0):

The comments under your original question seem to suggest that Microsoft Scripting Runtime is not available or not installed on your PC. This could be unintentional, but it might also be because IT administrators have limited access to that library in your environment.

Fortunately, there are a number of ways of writing a text file. You may be able to use the ADO library to write a stream..

Just add a Reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library` and then replace your code with:

```
Sub emailFile()

  ' Declare an ADO Stream.
  Dim stream As ADODB.stream

  ' Create an ADO Stream.
  Set stream = New ADODB.stream
  stream.Open
  stream.Type = adTypeText
  stream.WriteText "user Email.", stWriteLine
  stream.WriteText "Maki", stWriteLine
  stream.WriteText "Nigeri", stWriteLine
  stream.WriteText "Sashimi", stWriteLine
  stream.SaveToFile "C:\Users\eladt\Desktop\creatFile\Mail.txt", adSaveCreateOverWrite
  stream.Close

End Sub
```